# Обновление таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Например существует таблица в БД:

[image]

в php в массив из файла заносятся новые данные (юзеры) для этой таблицы, их нужно туда занести. Но те юзеры которые есть уже в таблице, но нет в массиве - нужно удалить из таблицы, если нет такого юзера - то добавить, которые совпадают - оставить.

Я не знаю, какой запрос нужно для этого составить. `update` или `replace` - не подходят насколько я понял. Т.е. нужно как-то совместить `insert` и `delete`? я не знаю как это сделать.

Мне в голову только вытащить все данные из таблицы в массив, обработать всё в `php` и сделать нужный конечный массив, потом удалить все записи из таблицы и по новой туда всё записать... но это плохой же способ?

Я не особо разбираюсь в `SQL`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делать?

Comment: Занести файл в таблицу (временную -- temporary), затем как нибудь

     delete from yourtable where user in (select user from yourtable y where user not exists in (select user from temptable t)

и вставить из временной таблицы недостающие insert into ... select ... where not exist (s

только не забывать давать таблице алиасы, чтобы таблица в insert и select не путалась.

И ещё -- нафига скриншот в вопросе? Проще вставить текст (хоть в линуксе, хоть в винде. В винде вроде менюшка в углу окошка).

Comment: ясно, спасибо, потом попробую :)

Comment: А чем плох вариант удаления данных исходной таблицы и последующего ввода данных из файла?

Отсутствующие удалятся, новые добавятся, а старые - обновятся.

И почему импорт происходит из файла? Так постоянно будет? Как данные попадают в файл? Может быть стоит работать напрямую с БД, минуя файл?

Comment: ну я сначала подумал, что если в таблице сотни строк, то посылать кучу запросов на добавление/удаление - это плохо для производительности, но теперь я понял, что это сложные запросы с подзапросами - не лучше, так что сойдёт.

ну я изобразил такую таблицу с юзерами для простоты, на самом деле вместо васи, пети и т.д. туда заносятся конф. настройки, а они прописаны в файле

на самом деле вопрос уже закрыт :)

Comment: @Comfmore Ну закрыт, так закрыт. Но

     то посылать кучу запросов на добавление/удаление - это плохо для производительности, но теперь я понял, что это сложные запросы с подзапросами - не лучше,

А вот с тем, что сложные запросы -- "не лучше", согласиться трудно. Оно (сложные запросы) крутится внутри sql-сервера, а мучения процессора php-скриптом должны быть потяжелее.